# Finding the center of a contour using opencv and visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to find the center of a contour without doing so much calculations. Is there a built in function for  that in opencv?

Comment: To answer your question: There is no built in function. Checkout berak for copypasta code that solves your problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

for the 'geometric center', get the [boundingRect()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#boundingrect) of the contour, then:

```
   cx = br.x+br.width/2; cy = br.y+br.height/2;
```

for the 'center of mass' get the [moments()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#moments) of the contour, then:

```
   cx = m.m10 / m.m00;   cy = m.m01 / m.m00;
```

Comment: Thank your answer was easy to implement not complicated like examples that I found.

Comment: Using "moments" can fail with ZeroDivisionError because of bad contours, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35247571/1619432 (no proper solution given).

Answer (score 1):

hope this could help you. this [link](https://learnopencv.com/find-center-of-blob-centroid-using-opencv-cpp-python/) has python and C++ code snippet

```
std::vector<cv::Point> centers; 
for (int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++){
     cv::Moments M = cv::moments(contours[i]);
     cv::Point center(M.m10/M.m00, M.m01/M.m00);
     centers.push_back(center);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you haven't done any research, or these questions already asked and answered here are not what you are asking:

[centroid of contour/object in opencv in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143414/centroid-of-contour-object-in-opencv-in-c)

[OpenCV 2 Centroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074202/opencv-2-centroid?rq=1)

If latter is the case, please elaborate the question in more detail.